# Getting the first dollar amount using JavaScript with Razor and .Net

Tags: javascript, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I asked a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259087/extracting-dollar-amounts-from-existing-sql-data/8263908#8263908) question on how to do this on the server side (SQL), however it makes more sense to accomplish this on the client side, based on the app architecture.

I've got a MVC3 app with Razor on the .Net framework, where I have model data available that I would like to parse and return the first dollar value from a given string using Javascript / regex,

For example, each of the following lines represents a sample data set:

```
Used knife set for sale $200.00 or best offer.
$4,500 Persian rug for sale.
Today only, $100 rebate.
Five items for sale: $20 Motorola phone car charger, $150 PS2, $50.00 3 foot high shelf.
```

I've seen a few issues already including the @ in JS and a few other pitfalls I would like to try to avoid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var m = line.match(/\$[0-9,]+\.?\d*/);
if (m)
    return m[0];
```

should give you a hint. This Regex returns you a string which consists of a dollar sign, some numbers or commata, and optional a dot another few numbers behind it. You might want to limit its wideness (only 2 decimals, not starting with zero etc).