# MSSQL2008 String Extract

Tags: regex, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extracting dollar amounts from existing sql data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259087/extracting-dollar-amounts-from-existing-sql-data)

I have a column in my MSSQL2008 database which contains row values such as this:

```
$10 / 1Mango

$12 / 2Mango + $11.95 / Great Casino

$11 Business Banana

$80 / XXXX + $12.34 / Soft XXX 24m

2*xpr Love $169.69

Good $5 Love

Longine $99 / 99Mango
```

How do I extract the $ values, such as $10 and add it to itself if there are more than one $ values in the same line, e.g. $12 / 2Mango + $11.95 / Great Casino to be equal to $23.95. Note that + separates a new entry of dollar values there can be more than 2 instances of $ values in which case how can automatically make it loop to generate me the total value and return as a money value?

Comment: Why do you have such awful data in your database?

Comment: haha! well, i had to edit the texts before I paste them here so that I don't give too much information away about my work. So thought I would use some funny texts

Comment: I more meant storing all kinds of unstructured data, including having special rules (the '+' rule) in a single column, rather than having structured data (you know, the thing that SQL databases are meant to store)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259087/extracting-dollar-amounts-from-existing-sql-data/8263908#8263908) to extract the amounts and this [function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str) to split the string

```
    declare @tbl as table(id int, texts nvarchar(max))

    insert into @tbl values 
        (1,
        '$10 / 1Mango
        $12 / 2Mango + $11.95 / Great Casino
        $11 Business Banana
        $80 / XXXX + $12.34 / Soft XXX 24m
        2*xpr Love $169.69
        Good $5 Love
        Longine $99 / 99Mango'),
        (2,
    '$20 / 1Mango
        $32 / 2Mango + $11.95 / Great Casino
        $1 Business Banana
        $480 / XXXX + $12.34 / Soft XXX 24m
        2*xpr Love $1629.69
        Good $5 Love
        Longine $99 / 99Mango')

  SELECT t.id, sum(a.Amount)
    from @tbl t
    cross apply dbo.fn_ParseText2Table(t.texts,'+')as f
    cross apply dbo.fnGetAmounts(f.txt_value) as a
    group by t.id, f.Position
    order by t.id
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767)  ;
```